# replace for " " (space) doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo">Click the button to locate where in the string a specifed value occurs.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
var a =" picture";
a.replace(" ","");


var n=a.indexOf(" ");
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML= n+a+n;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I would like to replace " "(Space) out from the " picture" in the example above

but the result seem it's not replace by the replace command.

The result should be "-1picture-1" after replace but it's "0 picture0"

with a space in front of picture. (I use .indexOf(" ") to indicate that

there are a space in the variable or not -1 mean it doesn't )

What's it happen?? Please advise

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`replace` doesn't modify the string in place, it *returns* a modified string.

```
a = a.replace(" ","");
```

Comment: FYI use `.replace(/ /g, '')` if there's more than 1 whitespace in your string and you want all replaced.

Answer (score 2):

Use `String.trim()` to remove trailing spaces.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim

In your example,

```
var a = " picture";
a = a.trim();
...
```

Comment: This could be used if the OP doesn't need to support IE 8 … but since it also *returns* the modified value instead of operating in place, it doesn't solve the problem. (Although the additional, unexplained, changes you made in your example would)

Answer (score 1):

I think this could works pretty well...

```
return str.replace(/\s+/g, '');
```

why I got a downvote???

```
alert("some #$%%&& person gave me a downvote!!".replace(/\s+/g, ''));
```

this totally works!!!!!!

http://jsfiddle.net/ncubica/FBxy2/

Comment: Person ncubica = new Person();                                                                    If(downVote(ncubica))     {                                                                                    ncubica.rage();   }

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the returned value back to `a`

```
var a =" picture";
a = a.replace(" ","");
```

**edit:**

Would also like to throw it out there that a `.replace(" ","")` will only work for the first instance of a space, and it may not even be at the beginning of the string.  If you are wanting to trim *only* leading *and* trailing spaces, consider this:

```
var a =" picture";
a = a.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
```